# Usage of $TRAVIS_OS_NAME in .travis.yml

Tags: travis-ci

I want to test a project on multiple platforms, so I am using according to the [docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/) `os:` and $TRAVIS_OS_NAME. But I seem to be missing something. My `.travis.yml` looks as follow:

```
os:
  - osx

before_install:
  - ./.travis.$TRAVIS_OS_NAME.before_install.sh

install:
  - ./.travis.$TRAVIS_OS_NAME.install.sh

script:
  - ./.travis.$TRAVIS_OS_NAME.script.sh
```

But i get the following [error](https://travis-ci.org/rkrug/homebrew-experimental/builds/76632573):

```
$ ./.travis.$TRAVIS_OS_NAME.before_install.sh

/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: ./.travis.linux.before_install.sh: No such file or directory
```

So it seems that the `os:` directive is ignored.

Am I missing something?

I have not included `os: -linux` as the tests scripts are not ready yet.